# Mysql query with one or more rows one status takes precedence Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I have the following fields:

```
| employee_email | status | id |
| test1@test.com |  active | 1 | 
| test1@test.com |  terminated | 2 |
| test2@test.com |  active | 3 |
| test3@test.com |  terminated | 4 |
| test4@test.com |  terminated | 5 |
| test4@test.com |  terminated | 6 |
```

I need to query with a rule that if there are more than 1 rows for the same employee_email (and one is active and one is terminated - then return just the row = active). IF more than 1 row and both are terminated, then return just one row that is terminated.

Output should be:

```
| employee_email | status | status |
| test1@test.com |  active | 1 |
| test2@test.com |  active | 3 |
| test3@test.com |  terminated | 4 |
| test4@test.com |  terminated | 5 |
```

Comment: Which one? And what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: I do have an auto-increment primary id. Column name = id

Comment: Please amend your question, data set, and desired result accordingly.

Comment: Completed with edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use window function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.employee_email, t.status, t.id
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_email ORDER BY status = 'active' DESC, id) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

For previous versions:

```
SELECT t.employee_email, MAX(t.status) status, MIN(t.id) id
FROM tablename t
WHERE t.status = 'active'
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE employee_email = t.employee_email AND status = 'active')
GROUP BY t.employee_email
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eb957a6e8f7d190cfc1b3ec1b9c47800).
Results:

```
> employee_email | status     | id
> :------------- | :--------- | -:
> test1@test.com | active     |  1
> test2@test.com | active     |  3
> test3@test.com | terminated |  4
> test4@test.com | terminated |  5
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately - I am on Mysql 5.7 (just added that to the title). Any ideas without upgrading to 8.0?

Comment: Check my 2nd query.